# Is a stack of steel plate as strong as a single plate of the sum thickness?

Tags: load-bearing, steel, driveway

I'd like to put a 4'x8' steel plate across my driveway gutter, so cars don't bottom out in the dip.  I've seen 1/2" plates used for this, but at 650+ lbs. (https://www.chapelsteel.com/weight-steel-plate.html), it will be a beast transport.  Will a stack of two 1/4" pieces have roughly the same bearing capacity?

Comment: No, it’s not as strong, but how far are you spanning across your driveway gutter?

Comment: @LeeSam I'd like to span 4 feet; it's a fairly deep gutter and the road has been repaved to a high camber.  It needs to be strong enough to hold a Prius (about 3k lbs. curb weight and fairly low clearance), but occasionally a 1/2 ton truck (estimated 2.4k per axle, when loaded)

Comment: Can you weld or set rivets?

Comment: Only the heavy load determines the strength required.

Comment: Would you consider shearing the 8' long plate into several sections (ie four 4'x2' pieces)? This could reduce the per-piece weight; the pieces could then be joined on site by welding or by splicing with thinner plate fastened by bolts, rivets, etc.

Comment: I'm with @GregHill here.  You'd find it easiest and simplest to put down something analogous to a  bunch of  "12 by  4" lumber sheets.  If they're well seated at both ends you don't absolutely have to bolt them together at all, or just mount the equivalent of a couple bar-clamps on the underside to keep the assembly aligned.

Comment: if you have access to a half-ton truck how is 650lb a problem?  pull it off the back with a rope tied to something solid, then work it into place with crowbars and rollers. (or a winch if you can borrow one)  if you a don't want to D.I.Y get the steel place to send a crane-truck to deliver it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  When you stack sheets of thin material, their strengths merely add.  And a thin sheet is exponentially weaker in bending than a thick one, so added up they are still quite poor.  The reason is they are free to slip past each other.

Think about how a wrapped 500-sheet pack of paper is fairly rigid,  but once you break the package, the 500 sheets are a wet noodle.  The strength is actually in the vertical sides of the package wrapper - and in turn, that vertical is being kept from  twisting by the horizontal sheets.

What makes a thick sheet so much stronger is having vertical sides *inside the material itself*. It's like the material has an internal truss.

The material doesn't even need to be solid, it just needs to be braced - the vertical element carries the weight, and horizontal elements keep the vertical from twisting or buckling.

For instance, you might use a stack of C-channel or Unistrut, with each segment bolted to the next.  The reason to bolt is both to distribute the weight and allow them to mutually reinforce each other.  Bolts should be well chosen, of comparable material/stretch (e.g. *don't* use Grade 8 bolts to bolt mild steel), and of suitable interval.

Answer (score 2):

Not unless you can bond them together into a single piece so they won't flex independently.  Otherwise it will act like a leaf spring.  But bonding them together defeats the goal of trying to reduce the weight of a 1/2" piece because they would just become one 1/2" piece.

Comment: unless you can bond them on site

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @GregHill here.  You'd find it easiest and simplest to put down something analogous to a  bunch of  "12 by  4" lumber sheets.  If they're well seated at both ends you don't absolutely have to bolt them together at all, or just mount the equivalent of a couple bar-clamps on the underside to keep the assembly aligned.

So if you use half-inch, or even 3/4-inch, plates  6 feet long and 1 foot wide (8 pieces) , that gives you plenty of footing space at both ends.    But really, I'd look into similarly sized grating plates rated for the kind of vehicle weights of interest. THey'll be much lighter, will drain & stay clean more easily, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler, easier, and cheaper solution is to make a culvert... you put a properly sized galvanized or pvc pipe in the gutter to allow drainage, (I can't say a size without seeing your driveway but 1 foot diameter is the most common, anything smaller can get leaves and other debris stuck inside too easily.)

then concrete (ed: atop fill) over its top to level out your drive way. If you need more than 0.5-1 cubic yard / 13ish-27 cubic feet of concrete, price check a concrete truck delivery service, as mixing your own by the bag quickly becomes more expensive than a delivery even with a small load fee tacked on.

For an example you can look for any road with a ditch alongside it. It should have a culvert at every drive way and intersection to prevent flooding.

Closing thought: I'mm slightly concerned you talking about the gutter in your street, in which case I don't think there is much you could do other than maybe have your drive way r made to a better angle. You wouldn't be allowed to modify city property and having half inch plates sticking out into the road would be a hazard.